# Why are some minimized applications not found icon tray?

Tags: windows

I've experienced this in XP and Windows 7, and with different applications that are supposed to live in the icon tray when minimized.

I noticed that sometimes, the application is running in the background but its icon isn't found in the icon tray. Here's an example with 2BrightSparks' SyncbackSE:

[image]

Again, I've seen this with other apps sometimes. Does someone know why that happens and what can be done about it?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you, by any chance, kill `explorer.exe` since the tray process has started?

Comment: No, but maybe Windows needed to be rebooted.